# Batch print PDF files listed in a text file

Tags: pdf, command-line, printing, batch-file, cmd

Hello I am new to CMD but I would like to make a batch printing solution.

I know that using:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t "C:\file_1.pdf"
```

I can print file_1.pdf but what I really need is to print multiple files, let's say file_2, file_3... file_n, therefore my instruction will change to:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t "C:\XXXX.pdf"
```

I thought about making a TEXT file where I could write the name of the files that I need to print. Then in a batch file make a loop that will read each line of the TEXT and change my variable XXXX for the name of the file specified in each row of the TEXT.

Is this possible? I'm not stupid and I learn fast so, if any body can point me in the right direction of how to do variables in batch files, and how to read information form a TEXT it would be fantastic.

Answer (score 3):

Run `for /?` in a cmd.exe Window and read the output, or see [**Loop command: against a set of files**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Basically, if you want to batch print all PDFs in a directory, you can do the following:

```
for %i in (*.pdf) do ^
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t %i
```

This is the line to be used if run directly in a 'DOS box' window. If run from a BAT file, you need to replace `%i` by `%%i`.

If you have the files-to-be-printed enumerated line by line in a *.txt file:

```
for /f %i in (mypdfs.txt) do ^
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t %i
```

<sub>(**Note:** I didn't test-run the commands, since I don't have a Windows system around, but I'm relying on my aging memory here...</sub>

Comment: Kurt: out of interest, why do you use the ^ instead of ()?

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh: `^` and `()` are not the same. The `^` in above context simply is simply a line continuation sign (in other DOS contexts it is an escape char). I used it for formatting reasons, so every bit of my command is visible in the browser. In Unix, Linux and Mac one would have to use `\. The `\(\) ` in a DOS batch file allows you to group command blocks (and also allows to use line breaks as Ken White did).

Comment: Yes, I understand both well.  I was just curious if you had a reason for presenting it the way you did as one logical line on two physical lines with ^ (it could equally well be presented on multiple physical lines using brackets).  In the windows world, I have rarely seen anyone use ^ to escape the line-ending.  Not that there is anything wrong with it, just wondering why you had a preference for it.

Comment: @DavidI.McIntosh: You rarely see the usage of `^` in the Windows world because hardly any batch script author knows about it. I prefer it because it can be used even where brackets don't work (brackets can only be used in certain contexts).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is what I was curious about.  cmd.exe often has problems parsing when () are involved.  I am curious if you have an example of where ^ would work but () fails? lol.  I'm now going to have to do some experimenting when I have time...

Comment: couldn't get the notification to work when editing the previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try 2Printer command line tool from:
http://doc2prn.com/

Printing list of PDF documents command line example:
2Printer.exe -l "C:\input files.txt" -prn "Canon MP610"

2Printer is free!

Comment: It's free for non-commercial use: ["Free version of 2Printer has the same features as the commercial version and will let you evaluate the program or use it for non-commercial needs. One limitation exists – informational page will appear in the print job."](https://www.doc2prn.com/download)

Answer (score 1):

All, to expand on Kurt's answer ... this is what I did:

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "Brother MFC-J6930DW Printer"
Timeout /T 10
CD\
cd Users\bill\Desktop\PrintMe
Timeout /T 2
for %%i in (*.pdf) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" /t "%%i"
Timeout /T 10
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 (Network)"
Pause
```

This batch file will change default printers, print everything in folder, then change default printer back

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started:

```
for /f %%i in (myfiles.txt) do (
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t "%%i%"
)
```

You can get more information about `for` syntax and options [here at MS Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900%28v=ws.10%29)