# SSIS print document task or other way to easily print file via SSIS package

Tags: t-sql, ssis, task

In SSIS, you can print a file using a batch file and then schedule the batch via SQL Job and  File System Task or use more [sophisticated solutions](http://johanmachielse.blogspot.nl/2013/07/generating-and-printing-ssrs-reports.html), but is there an easier way of sending files to a printer is SSIS (2008)?

For example, does a Print Document or Send to Printer task exist? I can't seem to find it, but you would expect such a basic task to be available in SSIS. With Print I mean sending it to document printer, not the print sql statement. I would like to create a SSRS report, save it in a folder and then print the document automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you want to print a Word document but word is not installed? Printing is application specific. You need an application to render a document before printing. Exactly what type of document do you want to print? Check it's application documentation and see how you print on the command line.

Comment: For example this shows the command line required to print a PDF document: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417335/batch-print-pdf-files-listed-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no "print file" task, or anything like it.  SSIS tasks tend to be very general, yet highly configurable.  You could use an Execute Process Task to print the file using win cmd.  Put it after a File System task that moves your report to the desired location.