# Batch print text files listed in a text file

Tags: file, batch-file, text, printing

I need to be able to print a bunch of text files from a batch command file.
The files that need to be printed are listed in a text file called printlist.txt

When you open printlist.txt you would see something like:

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
and so on.
```

I have some code started below that should loop through all the files listed in printlist.txt and prints them to my LaserJet using notepad /pt command line.
But the code below only prints the filename to the paper when it prints out.
So if there is 10 files listed in printlist.txt it prints 1 sheets of paper with only the filename instead of the file contents.

Any Ideas?

Here is the code:

```
for /f %%i in (printlist.txt) do (
  notepad /pt "%%i" "HP LaserJet 4" "%%i%"
)
```

Comment: What makes you think the params following `/pt` should be *filename printername filename*?

Comment: The notepad code I found here:
https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-use-notepadexe-from-command-prompt

And the other code I found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417335/batch-print-pdf-files-listed-in-a-text-file

Comment: You should open a command prompt and experiment with that command line (using one filename from your list and your printer name).

Comment: So that answers your question, right? Use `notepad /pt "%%i" "LaserJet"`? (The techwalla article you linked explains the two parameters and the order they have to be in, BTW. It does not mention repeating the filename at then end. And if the LaserJet is your default printer, you can just use `notepad /P "%%i"` instead.)

Comment: It showed it in an example near the bottom of that page. The LaserJet is not my default printer. Hopefully this will be helpful for somebody else.
In case somebody could use this here is the code I used to search all subdirectories to make a list of all text files listed within and write it to a text file.
    for /R %%f in (*.txt) do echo %%f >> printlist.txt

Comment: It's not going to be helpful to anyone else unless you write an answer that provides a solution, and you can't do that because you didn't have a problem in the first place. *Oops! The problem was that it was working exactly like it was supposed to; the files just had the wrong content because I messed them up trying to figure this out.* isn't going to be a useful answer. (And that example at the bottom of the page only shows `/pt "FileName" "Printer" - it does *not* repeat the filename again at the end, although doing so isn't an issue.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this post because the issue it describes is not reproducible, for the reasons outlined in my previous comment just above this one. There is no problem to solve, because the issue was not with the code posted but the poster having corrupted the input files previously, and it's unlikely that this will occur with other users. The code posted in the question works perfectly.